# NodeJS: Guarantee order of async functions

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

How can I ensure that the second function call is started after the first one finished execution?

```
const asyncFuntion = async (callNumber: string, timeout: number) => {
    await setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`call: ${callNumber}`, timeout);
    }, timeout);
};

asyncFuntion("1", 100);
asyncFuntion("2", 50);
```

Console output right now:

```
call: 2 50
call: 1 100
```

Desired console output:

```
call: 1 100
call: 2 50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`await` will have no effect on `setTimeout()` as it does not returns a promise.**

**So, the solution to this problem is to wrap `setTimeout` using `Promise`.**

Also, if you want first function call to be executed before the second, create promises and resolve them before you make a call to second one and make use of `await` for the first function call.

Have a look at the following implementation:

```js
const asyncFuntion = async (callNumber, timeout) => {

    return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => { 
        await setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`call: ${callNumber}`, timeout);
            resolve();
        }, timeout); 
    });
};

async function test() {

    /*Write the function calls in the order you want them to get executed*/
    await asyncFuntion("1", 100);
    await asyncFuntion("2", 50);
}

test();
```

PS: You should also await the second call so that the promise returned by test() fulfills at the appropriate time, not in the middle of running the two timeouts. **Credits @Bergi.**

Comment: You should also `await` the second call so that the promise returned by `test()` fulfills at the appropriate time, not in the middle of running the two timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

Two matters to notice.

1. Using `await` in front of `setTimeout` has no effect. It only works for functions which return a promise.
2. The execution order of the `setTimeout` solely depend on the interval - not on another iteration.

There is no way an interval of 100ms do something before the interval of 50ms.   If you want the second call to be waiting until the  completion of the first, create a promise and resolve it before you call the second one.

Answer (score -1):

Another way of doing it to manipulate the setTimeout timer, its not as elegent but works.

```js
let timer = 0
const asyncFuntion = (callNumber, timeout) => {
    timer += timeout
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`call: ${callNumber}`, timeout);
    }, timer);
};


asyncFuntion("1", 100);
asyncFuntion("2", 50);
```